# Is there an easy way to get which element fails a logical test?

Tags: javascript

Here is an example:

```
let foo = true;
let bar = true;
let ram = false;

if(foo && bar && ram){
//do something
}
```

I'd like to be able to use a method that returns whatever failed the test (in this case it would return 'ram') preferably without testing each variable in an else statement or something like that. I know there are many ways of doing this but was wondering what the most efficient/ standard practice would be. Another example that might be more practical:

```
let foo = 28;
if(foo < 4){
//do something
}
//magical fail detector would return foo or 28 or something like that
```

I appreciate any help. I looked through the mozilla docs for JS and didn't see anything that suggested an answer.

Comment: There is no facility in JavaScript to do that. Expressions are evaluated, and a final value is determined; no "recording" is maintained to capture what happened during the evaluation. You can of course create your own logic to do that in any particular case where you feel you need that kind of information.

Comment: Thank you @Pointy I figured that was likely the case. I'm happy to know that I didn't miss something super obvious.